# Permission Denied (publickey) when trying to SSH to Amazon EC2 server

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, ec2-ami

I am getting permission denied (public key) while doing a ssh to amazon machine. Here is the verbose output

```
OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-7ubuntu1,
OpenSSL 1.0.0e 6 Sep 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 46.137.248.46 [46.137.248.46] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file Desktop/tws/new_key.pem type -1
debug1: identity file Desktop/tws/new_key.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-7ubuntu1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 20:0f:a7:ea:b6:70:4f:ca:d0:d4:1c:31:2d:b2:08:71
debug1: Host '46.137.248.46' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/cs1090174/.ssh/known_hosts:43
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: cs1090174@aurora
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: Desktop/tws/new_key.pem
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

What can be the possible error? Thanks in advance for replying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, I got the fix. The username is not supposed to be Ubuntu but ec2-user .